# Cron - Does not execute command every 10 mins

Tags: linux, centos, cron, incrontab

I don't understand why cron is not really executing the command every 10 minutes.

in `crontab -e` I have added:

```
*/10 * * * * /var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl
```

I could see in the cron log it is running every 10 mins:

```
Mar 17 10:50:01 host crond[26335]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl)
Mar 17 11:00:01 host crond[26357]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl)
Mar 17 11:10:01 host crond[26418]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl)
Mar 17 11:20:01 host crond[26657]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl)
```

but it is not really executing the command.

When I execute that command manually in the Linux console it is working fine.

Comment: Did you check your email?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No? Where do I check that on Linux

Comment: try putting /path/to/perl in front of your command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about setup your crontab like this

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/myproject-recording-batch.log
```

then you can tail the log file  /var/log/myproject-recording-batch.log to trace the running

Answer (score 2):

CRON doesn't inherit all your environments variables. Some software must be manually called (ie: calling `ifconfig`or `/sbin/ifconfig` is not equal if you don't have a valid $PATH environment variable).

Also make sure it is executable and that your shebang is correctly defined (otherwise you'll have to prepend your command with the interpreter).

Answer (score 2):

As CloudWeavers said, it most be about a missing environmental variable, to check what exactly is missing you can edit the cronjob to log all it's standard output/error to a log file, so that you can review it to get what's stopping it:

```
*/10 * * * * /var/www/myproject/recording/batch.pl &> output.log
```